# Postgres array of doubles

Tags: postgresql

I have a big array of doubles, I am not sure which datatype to choose best. I have seen `integer[]` but not a double one.

Also, idea is that I dont want to search over the array or query specific indexes I just one to save and download it at once.

Could you please recommend datatype to store a double array.

Comment: `double[]`? But you most probably do **not** want `double`, better use `numeric`. See this for more details why: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: `double precision[]` ?

Comment: Also, idea is that I dont want to search over the array or query specific indexes I just one to save and download it at once.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment above, you're stating that your use case is restricted to simply loading/saving the whole matrix at once? Could you investigate compressing your matricies and storing the compressed representation? This is basically a separate topic on compression. However, whatever compress scheme you choose may result in an easier mechanism for storing the content.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, for me it worked: float8[] and I was generating postgres tables with liquibase
**https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html**